# Android Application not installing

Tags: android

I made a android application on my pc. I kept the build sdk at 4.1, and minimum sdk version at 2.2
 The app ran fine on the emulator but when i tried it on my friends Samsung Note it after installing gave an error "Application Not installed". I did so on Google Nexux 7.

I exported the app as a unsigned apk

I tried a simple hello world ap but had the same problem. Please help what to do and how to correct the error.

Comment: Does your friend have "Allow third party apps installed" checked on the device?

Comment: is it like a software or that allow untrusted apps checkbox?

Comment: Some devices have them in the settings and you have to check that to install if not from the Play store. It might be that one. It could be different on various devices

Comment: ok lemme jus ask this to him

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/android/aRTQeNA9/Author_List.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to sign the app to make it run on a real device.. simple choose export as a signed apk and sign it with a keystore...if you don't have one you can make a new keystore through same wizard that you get at the time of exporting

Comment: someoe please try this for me!!

Comment: it installed and ran on my phone

Comment: glad it sorted out...you should upvote or select an answer now.. if mine didn't help you can write your own answer and accept it. If you think it nothing more than a signing error and there's no suitable answer for this question, then you can simply vote to delete this question.